# C linked list - pointer indirection

Tags: c, list, pointers

I am trying to create a linked list in C, but I get this weird warning, and I have no idea how to get rid of it (except using pragma), even though that it seems to be working properly. I tried using a double pointer, as well as having a pointer attribute in the 'create' function, but no success so far. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#pragma once
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct node *node_ptr; // node pointer type
typedef struct list *list_ptr; // list pointer type

void create(list_ptr);
```

Implementation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

typedef struct node {
    void * e;               // element
    node_ptr next;          // next pointer
}node_t;

typedef struct list {
    node_ptr front;         // front pointer
}list_t;

void create(list_ptr self) { // create a list
    self->front = NULL;
}
```

On the create() line I get those warnings, but they don't make much sense to me.

```
#include "list.h"

void main(void) {
    list_ptr list = NULL;
    create(&list);
}
```

Warnings:

```
warning C4047: 'function': 'list_ptr' differs in levels of indirection from 'list_ptr *'
warning C4024: 'create': different types for formal and actual parameter 1
```

Comment: `create(&list);` <- `list` already **is** a pointer. That's what you get for hiding pointers behind a `typedef`. Don't do that.

Comment: also, strongly consider redoing your architecture to avoid using `void*` as a data type.

Comment: @yano uhm what? `void *` is the generic pointer, so for a generic linked list, it's the correct choice to hold the element.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: the trouble is that you can mistreat the pointers. It also means the data is not controlled by the list; it merely manages pointers to data managed externally. You can do it with `void *` but it is often better not to.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Sure, if this is intended to be a generic linked list... which I guess it is. Context clues tell me that'd be an odd task for the OP, however.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well it really depends. For a generic container in a reusable component, you don't have much of a choice in C. Of course you don't do that when your data structure is directly coupled to be used as a linked list. Anyways, I think it's unrelated here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `list` in `create()` otherwise you are passing  `struct node **`

**'function': 'list_ptr' differs in levels of indirection from 'list_ptr *'** Here it is saying it clearly that you are passing `list_ptr*` which is different from `list_ptr` itself.

<sub>As it is basically intialization it is better to give it a name of `init` rather than `create`. - ikegami's comment</sub>

Comment: Moved the typedef struct list to list.h, and instead of list_ptr I used list_t. Seems to work much better and makes sense. Thanks.